# why member function inherit from base is undefined?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am going to write some class for test like following files.
I get some errors when I compile those files: I call inherited function via derived class. but the compiler says that `undefined reference to 'Base<someStruct>::func()'`.

I get this error where I try to call inherited member function actually.

the base class and derived class are in the same file. why I get this error?

```
//tool.h
template <class Addr>
struct Base {
...
public:
    bool func();
...
}

class Tool : public Base<struct someStruct> {
...
public:
    int func1();
...
}
```

and the following is implementation file.

```
//tool.cpp
#include "tool.h"

template <class Addr>
bool Base<Addr>::func()
{
    ...
}

int Tool::func1()
{
}
```

the `main` is here:

```
//test.c
#include "tool.h"

int main()
{
    Tool tool;

    tool.func();  //error is here;
}
```

Comment: No need to write `struct` everywhere

Comment: @StoryTeller I have edited the question. I sure there is no `struct` in the definition in my real code.

Comment: Well, it was more a comment towards style. It has now bearing on the answer (which is in the duplicate link).

Comment: @StoryTeller OK, in a words, we need to put template class and its implementation together.